# select query in room db kotlin?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am building an android app.In that app we need to implement select query with where clause ,using kotlin.

```
@Query(value = "Select * from AddEntity where type= +'Bird'")
fun getAllbirdModule() : List<AddEntity>
```

we are try this code but it is not working.

Comment: The query is not correct, kindly checkout : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass type in function rather than using hardcode value in Query like this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from AddEntity WHERE type = :type")
fun getAllbirdModule(type: String) : List<AddEntity>
```

or remove + sign

```
@Query(value = "Select * from AddEntity where type='Bird'")
fun getAllbirdModule() : List<AddEntity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
@Query(value = "Select * from AddEntity where type='Bird'")
fun getAllbirdModule() : List<AddEntity>
```